# Espresso: returning to application

Tags: java, android-espresso

I have test in Espresso, at the end of the test I press call button in application, which leads to dialing screen of the phone.

How can I return back to application?
I want to return to application to log out from it.

`pressBack();` doesn't do anything.

Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: How about to just start the last app activity using the startActivity method?

Comment: @user1055395 I've used UIAutomator in the end. You can check code in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 UiDevice mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
mDevice.pressRecentApps();
mDevice.pressRecentApps();
```

I've used UIAutomator in the end. Exactly what I need.

Comment: This works great stepping through my test in the debugger but when it runs normally, the second call doesn't seem to do anything and my test ends with the device on the recent apps list. I tried adding `UiDevice#waitForIdle()` calls but that didn't help. Did you run into any similar problems you were able to address?